# UITextField not giving any suggestions with UITextContentType

Tags: ios, swift

Something as simple as the following code wont work for me to autofill an email for example, I've tried with phonenumbers, given names etc. as well. Even after forcing autocorrectionType.

```
let textField = UITextField()
textField.textContentType = .emailAddress
textField.autocorrectionType = .yes
textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(textField)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
    textField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
    textField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
    textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
])
```

Swift 5, Xcode 10.2, iOS 12.2

Comment: Anything on this? I am facing the same problem...

Comment: same issue here

Comment: Are you sure you are using a standard keyboard?

Comment: The same problem. Xcode 11.2.1 iOS 13.2.3

Comment: It's driving me crazy seeing no solutions to this.

Answer (score -3):

Try it this way. After typing `UITextContentType.` , You will get suggestions.

```
let test = UITextField()
test.textContentType = UITextContentType.emailAddress
```

Comment: You won't be able to access it directly using `.` symbol because it's not an enum. It has been defined as a typed variable (static variable) inside a struct.

Comment: Still doesn't work after adding UITextContentType.
Do I have to enable a capability for it to work? Maybe a device setting I don't have enabled? I've tried this on multiple devices with the same result. Even with a new project.

Comment: This is incorrect, you can access symbols that have been defined as static variables using the shortened . syntax.